# How to determine two dos devices is equals?

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to determine two dos device is the same.

e.g.

```
\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
\Device\HarddiskVolume2
```

How to resolve that?

The final goal is to get the Volume Name from the Dos Device Name.

But this is not possible, So I trying to compare it via FindFirstVolume.

---

(More detailed)

I need to find the Volume Name from Dos Device Name.

e.g. \Device\Harddisk0\Partition1 to \?\Volume{316eddba-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}.

QueryDosDevice function can get Dos Device Name from Volume Name. But it's reverse is can not.

So, I trying to this.

1. Enumerating all volumes via FindFirstVolume.
2. Find each Dos Device Name from volume names via QueryDosDevice.
3. Find wanted volume name with comparing found dos device name at 2 with input Dos Device Name.

Now, step 2 is the problem.

Comment: *But this is not possible* - you sure ? i dont think so

Comment: @RbMm There is no inverse function of DosDeviceQuery.

Comment: and so what ? what exactly you have as input (and how you get it) and what you want on output ?

Comment: After enumerating all dos devices through FindFirstVolume and DosDeviceQuery, it compares with the input dos device to finally find the volume name.

Comment: what you write is unclear

Comment: Okay, I edited. Thanks.

Comment: for what you at all use `FindFirstVolume` instead direct use `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS` ?

Comment: "\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1" is not a DOS device name. That's a native NT object path, which since NT 5.0 is implemented as an object symbolic link to an enumerated volume device such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2". To open a native device path, use the "GLOBALROOT" object symbolic link, e.g. "\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1". Then you can query the mountpoint manager for the DOS and GUID names. If the volume is mounted by a filesystem, then you can also append a trailing backslash to the path, open a handle and call `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW(h, sz, cch, VOLUME_NAME_GUID)`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/displaying-volume-paths

Comment: Perhaps the point is missed that the OP needs to determine whether "\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1" (an object symlink) is the same as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2". WinAPI volume enumerations and `QueryDosDeviceW` are insufficient. You'll only get the enumerated volume device name, such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2". To resolve the symbolic link, it's simplest to just open the path and query the interface between the mountpoint manager and volume devices, such as `IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME`, or use the undocumented NT API query `NtQueryObject` : `ObjectNameInformation` (1).

Comment: It's not documented, but Windows XP added `IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_STABLE_GUID`, which allows directly querying the GUID that's used for the "Volume{GUID}" name. See "km\mountdev.h".

Comment: **1** - how you get *\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1* **2** why you need convert it to *\?\\Volume{...}* form

Comment: Finally, I got the desired result through below! Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the desired result through below!

Thanks for all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#define MOUNTMGRCONTROLTYPE 0x0000006D// 'm'
#define MOUNTDEVCONTROLTYPE ((ULONG) 'M')

#define IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS      CTL_CODE(MOUNTMGRCONTROLTYPE, 2, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME CTL_CODE(MOUNTDEVCONTROLTYPE, 2, METHOD_BUFFERED,  FILE_ANY_ACCESS)

    typedef struct _MOUNTDEV_NAME {
  USHORT NameLength;
  WCHAR Name[1];
} MOUNTDEV_NAME, *PMOUNTDEV_NAME;

typedef struct _MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT {
  ULONG SymbolicLinkNameOffset;
  USHORT SymbolicLinkNameLength;
  USHORT Reserved1;
  ULONG UniqueIdOffset;
  USHORT UniqueIdLength;
  USHORT Reserved2;
  ULONG DeviceNameOffset;
  USHORT DeviceNameLength;
  USHORT Reserved3;
} MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT, *PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT;

typedef struct _MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS {
  ULONG Size;
  ULONG NumberOfMountPoints;
  MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT MountPoints[1];
} MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS, *PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS;

#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32.lib")

int main() {
  HANDLE hDevice, hMountMgr;
  BYTE byBuffer[1024];
  PMOUNTDEV_NAME pMountDevName;
  DWORD cbBytesReturned, dwInBuffer, dwOutBuffer, ccb;
  PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT pMountPoint;
  BOOL bSuccess;
  PBYTE pbyInBuffer, pbyOutBuffer;
  LPTSTR pszLogicalDrives, pszDriveRoot;

  // MOUNTMGR_DOS_DEVICE_NAME is defined as L"\\\\.\\MountPointManager"
  hMountMgr = CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\MountPointManager"),
                         0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                         NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
  if (hMountMgr == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return 1;

  LPCTSTR DOS_SYM_LINK = _T("\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\Harddisk0\\Partition1");
  //LPCTSTR DOS_SYM_LINK = _T("\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\HarddiskVolume1");
  hDevice = CreateFile(DOS_SYM_LINK, 0,
                       FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                       NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

  bSuccess = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,
                             IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME,
                             NULL, 0,
                             (LPVOID) byBuffer, sizeof(byBuffer),
                             &cbBytesReturned,
                             (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);
  pMountDevName = (PMOUNTDEV_NAME) byBuffer;
  _tprintf(TEXT("\n%.*ls\n"), pMountDevName->NameLength / sizeof(TCHAR), pMountDevName->Name);

  CloseHandle(hDevice);

  dwInBuffer = pMountDevName->NameLength + sizeof(MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT);
  pbyInBuffer = (PBYTE) LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, dwInBuffer);
  pMountPoint = (PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT) pbyInBuffer;
  pMountPoint->DeviceNameLength = pMountDevName->NameLength;
  pMountPoint->DeviceNameOffset = sizeof(MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT);
  CopyMemory(pbyInBuffer + sizeof(MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINT), pMountDevName->Name, pMountDevName->NameLength);

  dwOutBuffer = 1024 + sizeof(MOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS);
  pbyOutBuffer = (PBYTE) LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, dwOutBuffer);
  bSuccess = DeviceIoControl(hMountMgr,
                             IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS,
                             pbyInBuffer, dwInBuffer,
                             (LPVOID) pbyOutBuffer, dwOutBuffer,
                             &cbBytesReturned,
                             (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);

  PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS mount_points = (PMOUNTMGR_MOUNT_POINTS) pbyOutBuffer;
  printf("RESULT, %d: count = %d\n", bSuccess, mount_points->NumberOfMountPoints);

  for (int i = 0; i < mount_points->NumberOfMountPoints; i++) {
    auto item = mount_points->MountPoints[i];
    _tprintf(TEXT(" mountpoints[%d]: device name = %.*ls\n"), i, item.DeviceNameLength / sizeof(TCHAR), (LPCTSTR)(pbyOutBuffer + item.DeviceNameOffset));
    _tprintf(TEXT(" mountpoints[%d]: symbolic name = %.*ls\n"), i, item.SymbolicLinkNameLength/ sizeof(TCHAR), (LPCTSTR)(pbyOutBuffer + item.SymbolicLinkNameOffset));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume1
RESULT, 1: count = 1
 mountpoints[0]: device name = \Device\HarddiskVolume1
 mountpoints[0]: symbolic name = \??\Volume{0613c9d3-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}
```

Comment: Hi @user212942, thanks for sharing the solution and you could also feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).